# How to stay fit and eat clean while being a college student?

Tags: strength-training, programs

I am a college student, and wanted to know since I am stuck with the meal plan, and don't have much income to go out and buy groceries every other weekend, what are good ways to eat healthy and how to stay motivated to go to the gym, since being an engineer student is tough, since school work takes a lot of my energy.

Comment: Such a broad question has only broad answers, and it will amount to "go to the gym, eat healthy food, get a good night's sleep every night". Other than that, you're going to have to be more specific in your question. It takes 15 seconds to write that question, but hours to answer fully.

Comment: In addition, if you look to the right side of the page at "related" questions, that may give you a starting point. Once you put together a program, edit it into your question and we can give you feedback.

Comment: Well I am trying to be lean but don't know any specific way to start a diet, to stay lean.